# I am using the following code to check if the new week matches with the already created week and then showing an alert

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the following code to check if the new week matches with the already created week and then showing an alert.

```
$scope.addWeek =  function(type,newWeek,index){
    var c = $scope.weekList.length + 1;
    var newWeek = {"weekName":newWeek,"modifiedTime": $filter('date')(new Date(), "h:mm a MMM d, yyyy")};

    var weekList=  $scope.weekList;
        for(j=0;j<weekList.length;j++){
            if(weekList[j].weekName == newWeek){
                alert("The week already exists.");
                $("#"+ type + "weekmodalpopup").modal('toggle');
            }
            else {
                $scope.weekList.splice(0, 0, newWeek);
                $("#"+ type + "weekmodalpopup").modal('toggle');
            }
        }

//  $scope.weekList.splice(0, 0, newWeek);
//  $("#"+ type + "weekmodalpopup").modal('toggle');
};
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: When I click on the create button in my popup modal, everything hangs. I had to forcefully close the webpage and then to open it again.

Comment: Yes, because your original code added a new element to the array at each step of `for`, expanding that array; basically, it went to neverending loop - you never reach the end of always-expanding array. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use the name `'newWeek'` for a function parameter and a local variable at the same time. In your case, you reassign an object to this variable, then attempt to compare each element of `weekList` with that object. And that comparison is destined to fail: objects are compared by references, and a newly created object is referenced only by `newWeek` variable.

Apparently, you can fix it with separating the names. One approach would be to rename the local variable into `newWeekObject` or something like that; another - to rename a function parameter into `newWeekName`. I'd go with the latter; in fact, I'd drop that local variable completely, because, as you'll see, it's not even required. )

Second, the whole approach seems to be flawed: your code goes through `$scope.weekList` array, comparing each element's name with `newWeekName`. Currently, at *each* step you either show an alert OR insert a new element into array; apparently, the latter increases the array's length. That's why the code goes into an infinite loop, causing the page to hang.

What you should do instead with this loop is just checking whether or not a target week exists; set some flag, and decide, whether or not you'd insert a new week into a list, based on that flag. And you can rewrite this in a more concise way with `Array#some` method. For example:

```
$scope.addWeek = function(type, newWeekName, index) {
  var weekExists = $scope.weekList.some(function(week) {
    return week.weekName === newWeekName;
  });
  if (weekExists) {
    alert("The week already exists.");
  }
  else {
    $scope.weekList.unshift({
      weekName: newWeekName, 
      modifiedTime: $filter('date')(new Date(), "h:mm a MMM d, yyyy")
    });
  }
  $("#" + type + "weekmodalpopup").modal('toggle');
};
```

I've used `unshift` here instead of `splice(0, 0)`, as it's essentially the same action. But if you actually wanted to insert a new week at the `index` point, just replace it with `$scope.weekList.splice(index, 0, { ... }`.

Comment: something is missing in the above code

Comment: There was a typo in `if`; rewrote it, adding `weekExists` var for clarity.

Comment: it worked perfectly. Thanks. My bad on using the for loop incorrectly.